# Algorithm to "spread" decreasing value on 3D array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm

I need to find an efficient algorithm that does this:

```
byte[,] initialArray

0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   5   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

To this:

```
byte[,] resultArray

0   0   0   1   2   1   0   0   0   0
0   0   1   2   3   2   1   0   0   0
0   1   2   3   4   3   2   1   0   0
1   2   3   4   5   4   3   2   1   0
0   1   2   3   4   3   2   1   0   0
0   1   2   2   3   2   1   0   0   0
1   2   3   2   2   1   0   0   0   0
2   3   4   3   2   1   0   0   0   0
3   4   5   4   3   2   1   0   0   0
2   3   4   3   2   1   0   0   0   0
```

**What's happening**

The initial array has two cells that are set to an initial value, the other cells are set to 0. The algorithm needs to "spread" that value to neighbor cells (no diagonals, just up/down/left/right). Each time the value spreads to a new cell, the value is decreased by 1 and spreads again, recursively. When the value reaches 0 it stops.

If the value is spreading to a cell with value > 0, the largest of the two values should be kept, instead of simply overwriting.

The example shows a 2D array but I'm actually working with a 3D array.

**My attempt**

I've managed to make a simple recursive algorithm in C#. It works but it must be terribly inefficient. It's way to slow on a large 3D array with 4 initial cells with value >= 10. There must be a much better way of doing this (for those who are familiar, this is the method the Minecraft game uses to determine light intensity of each cell in the game. Minecraft level arrays are massive and can contain many light sources)

I'm looking for the most efficient way of doing this. Here is my C# implementation for 3D arrays:

```
main ... {

    List<int[]> toCheck = new List<int[]>(); 

    // This list will keep a record of the initial cells that have a value > 0
    // For loop over each cell to find those with initial value > 0

    for (int x=0; x<worldX; x++){
        for (int y=0; y<worldY; y++){
            for (int z=0; z<worldZ; z++){

                if (data[x,y,z].light > 0)
                    toCheck.Add (new int[] {x,y,z});

            }
        }
    }

    // For each cell w/ initial value > 0, spread the light
    foreach (int[] i in toCheck) 
        SpreadLight(i[0],i[1],i[2],(byte)(data[i[0],i[1],i[2]].light - 1));


}


void SpreadLight(int x, int y, int z, byte light) {

    try {
        // Make sure this cells current value is smaller than the value we want to assign to it
        if (data[x,y,z].light < light) {
            data[x,y,z].light = (byte)light;
        }

        // If the value at this cell is > 0, get adjacent cells and spread the light to each of them
        if (light > 0) {
            int[][] adjBlocks = GetAdjacentBlocks(x,y,z);
            for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                SpreadLight(adjBlocks[i][0], adjBlocks[i][1], adjBlocks[i][2],(byte)(light-1));
            }
        }
    }
    catch { return; }  // I'm not proud if this, it's the easiest way I found to avoid out of array bounds error

}


// This method simply returns an array with the 3D coordinates of each adjacent cell
int[][] GetAdjacentBlocks(int x, int y, int z) {
    int[][] result = new int[6][];

    // Top
    result[0] = new int[] {x, y+1, z};
    // North
    result[1] = new int[] {x, y, z+1};
    // East
    result[2] = new int[] {x+1, y, z};
    // South
    result[3] = new int[] {x, y, z-1};
    // West
    result[4] = new int[] {x-1, y, z};
    // Bottom
    result[5] = new int[] {x, y-1, z};

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You'll make your code a LOT slower using that `catch` approach to avoid array out of bounds error. There's a considerable overhead involved in throwing and catching exceptions...

Comment: I'd be surprised if Minecraft actually used that algorithm. More likely, when it goes to draw an object, it gets a list of all of the light sources that are within range, and then computes the light intensity from each source on that point. There's no need to compute the intensity of the light where there is no object to be drawn.

Comment: I would not use a 2D array (the title is misleading IMHO). I would use a 1D array with `index = N*row+column`. Solve the 2D problem first and then ask about taking it to the 3D.

Comment: I can think of a solution using an `N*M×N*M` sparse matrix using finite differences, but coding it would be a major undertaking.

Comment: @ja72: My mind went down the matrix avenue too - but, as you say, not exactly a picnic to code up! :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this. In my experience 1D arrays work much faster than 2D arrays. Also implemented are several shortcuts for the calculations.

## 2D version

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Area A=new Area(10, 10);
        A[3, 4]=5;
        A[8, 2]=5;

        Console.WriteLine(A);
        //0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
        //0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
        //0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
        //0   0   0   0   5   0   0   0   0   0  
        //0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
        //0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
        //0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
        //0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
        //0   0   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
        //0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
        bool spread1=A.CheckSpread();

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Spreading...");
        A.Spread();
        bool spread2=A.CheckSpread();

        Console.WriteLine(A);
        //0   0   0   1   2   1   0   0   0   0  
        //0   0   1   2   3   2   1   0   0   0  
        //0   1   2   3   4   3   2   1   0   0  
        //1   2   3   4   5   4   3   2   1   0  
        //0   1   2   3   4   3   2   1   0   0  
        //0   1   2   2   3   2   1   0   0   0  
        //1   2   3   2   2   1   0   0   0   0  
        //2   3   4   3   2   1   0   0   0   0  
        //3   4   5   4   3   2   1   0   0   0  
        //2   3   4   3   2   1   0   0   0   0  
    }
}

public struct Area
{
    byte[] map;
    int rows, columns;

    public Area(int rows, int columns)
    {
        this.map=new byte[rows*columns];
        this.columns=columns;
        this.rows=rows;
    }
    public Area(Area other)
        : this(other.rows, other.columns)
    {
        Array.Copy(other.map, this.map, other.map.Length);
    }
    public Area(byte[,] array)
    {
        this.rows=array.GetLength(0);
        this.columns=array.GetLength(1);
        this.map=new byte[rows*columns];
        for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<columns; j++)
            {
                this.map[i*columns+j]=array[i, j];
            }
        }
    }

    public int Rows { get { return rows; } }
    public int Columns { get { return columns; } }
    public byte[] Map { get { return map; } }

    public byte this[int index]
    {
        get { return map[index]; }
        set { map[index]=value; }
    }
    public byte this[int row, int column]
    {
        get { return map[row*columns+column]; }
        set { map[row*columns+column]=value; }
    }

    public byte[,] ToArray2()
    {
        byte[,] array=new byte[rows, columns];
        for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<columns; j++)
            {
                array[i, j]=map[i*columns+j];
            }
        }
        return array;
    }

    public void Spread()
    {
        bool changed;
        do // CAUTION: This is not guaranteed to exit. Or is it?
        {
            changed=false;

            for (int k=0; k<map.Length; k++)
            {
                byte x=map[k];
                if (x<=1) continue; // cannot affect neighbors

                int i=k/columns;
                int j=k%columns;

                int k_N=i>0?(i-1)*columns+j:-1;
                int k_S=i<rows-1?(i+1)*columns+j:-1;
                int k_E=j<columns-1?i*columns+j+1:-1;
                int k_W=j>0?i*columns+j-1:-1;

                if (k_N>=0&&map[k_N]+1<x) { map[k_N]=(byte)(x-1); changed=true; }
                if (k_S>=0&&map[k_S]+1<x) { map[k_S]=(byte)(x-1); changed=true; }
                if (k_E>=0&&map[k_E]+1<x) { map[k_E]=(byte)(x-1); changed=true; }
                if (k_W>=0&&map[k_W]+1<x) { map[k_W]=(byte)(x-1); changed=true; }
            }

        } while (changed); 
    }

    public bool CheckSpread()
    {
        for (int k=0; k<map.Length; k++)
        {
            byte x=map[k];
            if (x<=1) continue; // cannot affect neighbors

            int i=k/columns;
            int j=k%columns;

            int k_N=i>0?(i-1)*columns+j:-1;
            int k_S=i<rows-1?(i+1)*columns+j:-1;
            int k_E=j<columns-1?i*columns+j+1:-1;
            int k_W=j>0?i*columns+j-1:-1;

            if (k_N>=0&&map[k_N]+1<x) return false;
            if (k_S>=0&&map[k_S]+1<x) return false;
            if (k_E>=0&&map[k_E]+1<x) return false;
            if (k_W>=0&&map[k_W]+1<x) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string[] table=new string[rows];
        for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
        {
            string[] row=new string[columns];
            for (int j=0; j<columns; j++)
            {
                row[j]= string.Format("{0,-3}", map[i*columns+j]);
            }
            table[i]= string.Join(" ", row);
        }
        return string.Join(Environment.NewLine, table);
    }
}
```

## 3D version

```
public struct Area3
{
    byte[] map;
    int rows, columns, pages;
    public Area3(int rows, int columns, int pages)
    {
        this.map=new byte[rows*columns*pages];
        this.columns=columns;
        this.rows=rows;
        this.pages=pages;
    }
    public Area3(Area3 other)
        : this(other.rows, other.columns, other.pages)
    {
        Array.Copy(other.map, this.map, other.map.Length);
    }
    public Area3(byte[, ,] array)
    {
        this.rows=array.GetLength(0);
        this.columns=array.GetLength(1);
        this.pages=array.GetLength(2);
        this.map=new byte[rows*columns*pages];
        for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<columns; j++)
            {
                for (int l=0; l<pages; l++)
                {
                    this.map[(l*rows+i)*columns+j]=array[i, j, l];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public int Rows { get { return rows; } }
    public int Columns { get { return columns; } }
    public int Pages { get { return pages; } }
    public byte[] Map { get { return map; } }

    public byte this[int index]
    {
        get { return map[index]; }
        set { map[index]=value; }
    }
    public byte this[int row, int column, int page]
    {
        get { return map[(page*rows+row)*columns+column]; }
        set { map[(page*rows+row)*columns+column]=value; }
    }
    public byte[, ,] ToArray3()
    {
        byte[, ,] array=new byte[rows, columns, pages];
        for (int i=0; i<rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j=0; j<columns; j++)
            {
                for (int l=0; l<pages; l++)
                {
                    array[i, j, l]=map[(l*rows+i)*columns+j];
                }
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
    public void Spread()
    {
        bool changed;
        do
        {
            changed=false;

            for (int k=0; k<map.Length; k++)
            {
                byte x=map[k];
                if (x<=1) continue; // cannot affect neighbors

                int l=k/(rows*columns);
                int i=(k%(rows*columns))/columns;
                int j=(k%(rows*columns))%columns;

                int k_N=i>0?(l*rows+i-1)*columns+j:-1;
                int k_S=i<rows-1?(l*rows+i+1)*columns+j:-1;
                int k_E=j<columns-1?(l*rows+i)*columns+j+1:-1;
                int k_W=j>0?(l*rows+i)*columns+j-1:-1;
                int k_U=l<pages-1?((l+1)*rows+i)*columns+j:-1;
                int k_D=l>0?((l-1)*rows+i)*columns+j:-1;

                if (k_N>=0&&map[k_N]+1<x) { map[k_N]=(byte)(x-1); changed=true; }
                if (k_S>=0&&map[k_S]+1<x) { map[k_S]=(byte)(x-1); changed=true; }
                if (k_E>=0&&map[k_E]+1<x) { map[k_E]=(byte)(x-1); changed=true; }
                if (k_W>=0&&map[k_W]+1<x) { map[k_W]=(byte)(x-1); changed=true; }
                if (k_U>=0&&map[k_U]+1<x) { map[k_U]=(byte)(x-1); changed=true; }
                if (k_D>=0&&map[k_D]+1<x) { map[k_D]=(byte)(x-1); changed=true; }
            }

        } while (changed);
    }

}
```

No visualization coded for 3D.

Comment: This code can be expanded to 3D readily with the addition of another dimension `pages`. Since the main loop covers all the elements the extra time is only N× the 2D case.

Comment: So I was bored and coded up the 3D version also. Enjoy!

Answer (score 2):

The following implementation (2D) should be faster - it keeps object creation and unnecessary function calls to the minimum. Extending to 3D would be quite straightforward:

```
class Program
{
    class ArrayPoint { public int x; public int y;}

    private static byte[,] startArray =
    {
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},
        {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,0},{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
    };

    private static int rows = startArray.GetLength(0);
    private static int cols = startArray.GetLength(1);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Spread(startArray);
    }

    static void Spread(byte[,] array)
    {
        var points = GetStartPoints(array);

        foreach (var point in points.ToList())
            SpreadPoint(array, point.x, point.y);

        Display(array);
    }

    static void SpreadPoint(byte[,] array, int x, int y)
    {
        for (var i = x-1; i < x+2; i++)
            for (var j = y-1; j < y+2; j++)
                if (  (i==x || j==y) && !(i==x && j==y) && (i >= 0 && i < rows && j >= 0 && j < cols)
                    && array[i, j] + 1 < array[x, y])
                {
                    array[i, j] = (byte)(array[x, y] - 1);
                    SpreadPoint(array, i, j);
                }
    }

    static void Display(byte[,] array)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                Console.Write("{0} ",array[i,j]);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }


    static IEnumerable<ArrayPoint> GetStartPoints(byte[,] array)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                if (array[i, j] != 0)
                    yield return new ArrayPoint {x = i, y = j};
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
0 0 0 1 2 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 2 3 2 1 0 0 0
0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0 0
1 2 3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0
0 1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0 0
0 1 2 2 3 2 1 0 0 0
1 2 3 2 2 1 0 0 0 0
2 3 4 3 2 1 0 0 0 0
3 4 5 4 3 2 1 0 0 0
2 3 4 3 2 1 0 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

My two cents: consider expanding the points at the same time along wavefronts. Individual wavefronts could thus be terminated when done earlier than others.

A simplified JavaScript example:

```
var s = new Array(81)
for (var i=0; i<81; i++){
    s[i] = i == 40 ? 5 : 0
}

var max = 5, m = 9, n = 9

function expand(wavefront){ 
    while (wavefront.val > 0) {

        //Southwest
        var tmpLoc = wavefront.loc--
        for (var i=0; i<max - 1 - wavefront.val; i++){
            s[tmpLoc] = wavefront.val
            tmpLoc += n + 1
        }
        //Southeast...
        //...
        wavefront.val--
    }
}

expand({loc: 49, val: 4})
```

`s` now looks like this:

```
        [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
        ,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0
        ,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0,0
        ,0,0,1,2,0,0,0,0,0
        ,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0
        ,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```